# Is there a way to generate the documentation for an RSpec test without actually running the test?

Tags: ruby, rspec

For each test in each spec file in a given directory, I would like to generate the output of `rspec spec --format documentation`, so it looks something like this:

```
something
  does something that passes
  does something that fails
  does something that is pending
```

I don't want it to actually run the tests. I would like a list so that I can gauge the current test coverage level. These are not unit tests, so RCov would be of no use.

Comment: Do't know if it's doable, but... why? Why not just run them?

Comment: Because they haven't been updated in over a year, and need to be redone against new browsers using new automation technology, new syntax, pretty much new everything. All I want is the list of scenarios so that we can get back the coverage we used to have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comes a few years too late :D, but here's what you can do:

```
rspec --dry-run --format documentation
```

Answer (score 1):

There used to be until we added one liners:

```
it { should do_something }
```

That form is widely used and can only generate documentation if it runs.

Comment: I should add that the tests were written for RSpec 1, so it's all `it "does something" do`.